# generic type to static method

Tags: java, generics

Example is pretty simple. What I want is written. The problems are in the comments.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
  private static class X<T> {
    public static T get() { return new T(); }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(X<Interger>.get()); // illegal start of type 
    // commenting out above yields:
    // error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
  }
}
```

The real confounder to me is the `error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context`. The error seems clear: the class & method are static but the type variable isn't. Can I make the type variable work in this static context.

Further, as the example is written, I don't understand why I get an `illegal start of type` error with nothing else. Is this because the error about the non-static type variable is hidden?

Comment: public static <T> T get() {return new T();} --- does this work?

Comment: @Grisgram no it does not since [`T` is erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) =)

Comment: @Turing85 More to the point, `T` may not have an accessible no-args constructor.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline no, `T` does not exist anymore at runtime =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `new T()`. For one thing, there is no guarantee that `T` has an accessible no-args constructor. Relevant here, there is no no-arg constructor for `Integer`.

Static methods, as well as instance methods and constructors, can have type parameters.

```
public static <T> T get() {
    // Can only legally return null or throw.
    ...
} 
...
System.out.println(X.<Integer>get());
```

What to use instead? Possibly an abstract factory of some sort, possibly `java.util.function.Supplier`.

Comment: There is no such thing as `java.util.function.Factory`.  Did you mean `Supplier`?

Answer (score 1):

While the type `X` is generic, the class `X` is not. In Java, there are no "generic classes" (only generic types). What was most probably intended is a generic parameter on the static method:

```
private static class X<T> {
    public static <T> T get() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Also, since [generics are erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), one cannot instantiate `T` (thus the three dots in the code above).

One would call the method like such:

```
...
X.<SomeConcreteType>get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Supplier maybe more suitable for you than static `X<T>.get`:

```java
public static class aClass {}

public static <T> aMethodWantToUseX(Supplier<T> x) {
    T t = x.get();
}

aMethodWantToUseX(aClass::new)
```